# Bing ADs API - GetGeoLocationsFileUrlRequest

Tags: c#, bing, bing-api, bing-ads-api

The below soap request when fired using soap ui returns a valid response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v11="https://bingads.microsoft.com/CampaignManagement/v11">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v11:DeveloperToken>DeveloperToken</v11:DeveloperToken>
      <v11:CustomerId>CustomerId</v11:CustomerId>
      <v11:CustomerAccountId>AccountId</v11:CustomerAccountId>
      <v11:AuthenticationToken>Auth Token</v11:AuthenticationToken>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v11:GetGeoLocationsFileUrlRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v11:Version>2.0</v11:Version>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v11:LanguageLocale>en</v11:LanguageLocale>
      </v11:GetGeoLocationsFileUrlRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However when I try to fire the same request by populating the details in Bing Ads API , I am seeing "Authentication token expired. Please renew it or obtain a new token." Below is the code that I am using -

```
    var getGeoLocationsFileUrlRequest = new GetGeoLocationsFileUrlRequest(null, "Auth Token", "Account ID", "Customer ID", "Developer Token", null, null, "2.0", "en");

    CampaignManagementServiceClient client = new CampaignManagementServiceClient();

    var getGeoLocationsFileUrlResponse = client.GetGeoLocationsFileUrl(getGeoLocationsFileUrlRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token lasts up to an hour, so you'll need to get new access and refresh tokens via [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/guides/authentication-oauth?view=bingads-12#authorizationcode). Also in case it helps [here](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-dotNet-SDK/blob/master/examples/BingAdsExamples/BingAdsExamplesLibrary/v12/GeographicalLocations.cs) is a GetGeoLocationsFileUrl C# example via ServiceClient.